# Creating link to stored file on server in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

It should be easy to do, but I have no clue even after days of googling.

I've create a simple web form using PHP which allows users to upload image files to server, and the information e.g. date, filename (unique, automatically renamed when uploaded), etc. is input into MySQL table create.

Can I know how to create a link on the 'unique filename' uploaded in MySQL field when displayed, so when user clicked, it will automatically open the server stored file per the unique filename?

Appreciate if anyone can help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You know the unique filename and you know how to get it from the db. What is you cannot do?

Comment: Perhaps I did not make my point clearly. I manage to upload file to server, and input the relevant information on MySQL table. What I cannot do is, to let user click on the filename in MySQL table, and retrieve/open the uploaded file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table contains fields `id`, `type` (MIME type) and `data` (binary data), this is a PHP script for that:

```
<?php //dispimg.php
//example usage: dispimage.php?id=123
$my = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$sql = sprintf('SELECT type, data FROM table WHERE id="%s" LIMIT 1', $my->real_escape_string($id));
if(!$queryResult=$my->query($sql)){
   //query failed, log mysqli_error() somewhere
}
elseif(!$queryResult->num_rows){
   header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
   echo 'File not found';
}
else($res=$queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
   //optionally, use application/octet-stream instead of a field from database
   header('Content-Type: '.$res['type']));
   // uncomment following line if you want to present the file as download
   //header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=download');
   echo $res['data'];
}
?>
```